# Create multiple sub dictionaries from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a usecase where I have to create multiple sub dictionaries to split a nested dictionary upto **5** levels

Lets assume that my dictionary looks like below.

```
[{ person: [{
"id" : "abc",
"name" : "xyz",
"address" : {"co-ord" : "123", "place" : "world"},
"previous companies" :[{"comp1" : "name1"}, {"comp2":"name2"}]
}]
}]
```

Now I need to create a list like

```
[
person:
    {
    "id" : "abc",
    "name" : "xyz",
    }
person_address:{
    "id" : "abc",
    "co-ord" : "123", 
    "place" : "world"
    }
person_companies:
    {
    "id" : "abc",
    [{"comp1" : "name1"}, 
     {"comp2":"name2"}]
    }
    ]
```

Every sub directory needs to have a `id` field. I tried traversing the nested dict and extracting each value and adding the same to sub dictionary but i am not even close to the solution. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: Could you also paste a code snippet of what you have done so far, please?

Comment: Try putting person / person_address / person_companies in quotes

Comment: @am9417 : I could come up with flattening the entire dictionary.

Comment: Please let me know why this question is negatively voted

Comment: Does the `person` object contain other keys than those four? If yes, do you have to extract only the three values (`person`, `person_address` & `person_companies`) or should you be able to get all the keys in that dictionary?

Comment: Yes it does.. I am looking for something generic

Comment: You should add a bit more info about the input data. Can there be more than one item in the list under the key `person`? Can that dictionary have keys other than `person`? Can the list, where the dictionary with the key `person` is present, have another items?

Answer (score 1):

```
mylst=[{ 'person': [{
"id" : "abc",
"name" : "xyz",
"address" : {"co-ord" : "123", "place" : "world"},
"previous companies" :[{"comp1" : "name1"}, {"comp2":"name2"}]
}]
}]
lst=[]
for k,v in mylst[0].items():    
    for ki in (v[0].keys()):
        d={}
        if(ki!='id'):
            d['Id']=v[0]['id']
            d[ki]=v[0][ki]
        if d:
            lst.append(d)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Id': 'abc', 'name': 'xyz'},
 {'Id': 'abc', 'address': {'co-ord': '123', 'place': 'world'}},
 {'Id': 'abc', 'previous companies': [{'comp1': 'name1'}, {'comp2': 'name2'}]}]
```

Comment: @Shash Hope this helps.

Comment: `for ki in v[0].keys()` does take only the first item in the list of `person` into account. However the asker didn't specify if there can be several items in that list...

Comment: @am9417 You are correct, I'm trying to solve what he asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the persons and get the ID of that person. Then loop through all the keys except `id` key. Create a dictionary that has two keys: `id` and `key`, inject data to `key` and `id` keys.

Store data by appending it to some kind of a data structure. Assumingly it has to be a list since you will have more than one person.

```
data = [{ "person": [{
    "id" : "abc",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "address": {"co-ord" : "123", "place" : "world"},
    "previous companies": [{"comp1" : "name1"}, {"comp2":"name2"}]
    }]
}]

root = {}

for item in data:

    person_data = item['person']

    for person in person_data:

        for key in person.keys():

            if key != 'id':
                sub_dict = {}
                sub_dict[key] = person[key]
                sub_dict['id'] = person['id']

                if not key in root:
                    root[key] = []

                root[key].append( sub_dict )
```

This would output dictionary which contains all the keys except `id` key: The dictionary elements furthermore contain a list of dictionaries that have two keys: actual data and the id of the person whose data was fetched. You could replace the inner dictionary with a tuple (`id`, `data`) because repeating the key is redundant.

```
{
'previous companies': [{'previous companies': [{'comp1': 'name1'}, {'comp2': 'name2'}], 'id': 'abc'}], 
'name': [{'name': 'xyz', 'id': 'abc'}], 
'address': [{'id': 'abc', 'address': {'place': 'world', 'co-ord': '123'}}]
}
```

Comment: yours is the closet to what i am looking at. I have edited the question a bit. Can you please help me with the same so that i can accept your answer. All that is required to have the key only once instead of twice.

Comment: The output has mistakes: one of the entries is just an array and not a key-value pair. That's not possible. You should be able to modify one of the answers to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You also Use Dictionaries Comprehensions

```
 mylst = [{'person': [{"id": "abc", "name": "xyz", "address": {"co-ord": "123", "place": "world"},
                      "previous companies": [{"comp1": "name1"}, {"comp2": "name2"}]}]}]

 print({'Person_' + (z.split())[-1]:[{'id': y['id'], z: y[z]}] for x in mylst for y in x['person'] for z in y.keys() if z != 'id'})
```

you will get this output:

```
 {'Person_address': [{'address': {'place': 'world', 'co-ord': '123'}, 'id': 'abc'}], 'Person_name': [{'id': 'abc', 'name': 'xyz'}], 'Person_companies': [{'previous companies': [{'comp1': 'name1'}, {'comp2': 'name2'}], 'id': 'abc'}]}
```

It is Dictionaries Comprehensions if you want to write in simple way

```
  for x in mylst:
     for y in x['person']:
        for z in y.keys():
            print({'Person_' +(z.split())[-1]: [{'id': y['id'], z: y[z]}]})
```

Now I hope you understand what I did and still you have any doubts then ask me

Comment: Can you please explain this? Looks too complicated for me

Comment: @Shash I think you got your answer